# Comparing the average RGB value of an image in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, average, rgb

I am trying to recognize an image by the average RGB value of the image.
However, this value may have slight deviations in the RGB value. I have an array of exact values, but when checking, I would like to check the values 5 more and smaller in each element.

For example, if I have a red color with a value of 30, I would like to check this color from 25 to 35, and the same with green and blue

I have a numpy array, if I print it, it looks like this:
[27. 26. 25.]
If it displays one element, it has the following form:
27.0

This is what the code looks like at the moment, I test it on the Windows calculator image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygetwindow
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image


path = '../../Desktop/image.png'
titles = pygetwindow.getAllTitles()
flashes = [["25.", "26.", "27."]]

window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Calculator')[0]
left, top = window.topleft
right, bottom = window.bottomright
pyautogui.screenshot(path)
im = Image.open(path)
im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
im.save(path)

src_img = cv2.imread(path)
average_color_row = np.average(src_img, axis=0)
average_color = np.round(np.average(average_color_row, axis=0))
print(average_color)

arr = np.array2string(average_color)
i = iter(average_color)

for x in flashes:
    for y in x:
        arr = np.array2string(next(i))
        print(y)
        print(arr)
        if y == arr:
            print("TRUE")
```

I would like to use loops to check if R, G, B from the checked photo are in this range.

For example, my photo has such an average RGB [25. 25. 25.]
this should show true if checked against these values [27. 26. 25.].

I try to loop around it but I don't know how to finish it to see if all 3 values fit into 3 different ranges.

Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: See `cv2.inRange()`

Answer (score 0):

I would do a difference between the RGB triplets and then check if any of the values are greater than a treshold:

```
# This is a list of values to compare against, I imagine you will have several triplets to compare. 

flashes = [["25.", "26.", "27."], ...]

#This is the average calculated from an image, so only one triplet
# ...
average_color = np.round(np.average(average_color_row, axis=0))

#First loop selects the triplet
results = []
for triplet in flashes:
   
    #Convert strings to floats
    ftriplet = [ float(i) for i in triplet ]
    diff = np.abs(average_color - np.array(ftriplet))
    threshold = 3
    results.append( np.any(diff > threshold ) )
```

The results are a vector of True or False depending whether there was a  value greather than your threshold.

Comment: @PaweT it's good practice to accept the answer, if it's useful. I am glad it helped!!